# Is there a limit to jquery-steps content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am using jquery steps to show users a form, but I am running into a bit of a strange problem with the content property.

If I have both `" "` on one line of code, the steps work.

However, if I move the closing `"` to another line by adding another input field, the steps do not render.

```
$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

    //only apply to first step

    if (currentIndex === 0 && ($("#workType > option:selected").val()) === "1") {

        $("#wizard").steps("insert", 1, {
            title: "Construction Details",
            content: "<input type='text' name='budget' id='budget' placeholder='What is your budget?'><br/>"
        });
    }
});
```

So This works:

```
content: "<input type='text' name='budget' id='budget' placeholder='What is your budget?'><br/>"
```

This does not:

```
 content: "<input type='text' name='budget' id='budget' placeholder='What is your budget?'>
           <input type='text' name='timeline' id='timeline' placeholder='When do you want to start?'>
                            <br/>"
```

Does the content need to all be placed on one line or am I doing something wrong?  TIA

Comment: append the new line strings using `+` . `"string"+
"string2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try concatenating string using `+` like:

```
content: "<input type='text' name='budget' id='budget' placeholder='What is your budget?'>" + 
           "<input type='text' name='timeline' id='timeline' placeholder='When do you want to start?'> +
           "<br/>";
```

or another way:

```
var content_str = [
    '<input type='text' name='budget' id='budget' placeholder='What is your budget?'>',
    '<input type='text' name='timeline' id='timeline' placeholder='When do you want to start?'>',
    '<br />'
].join('');
...
contnet: content_str
```